# Trying to upload a package through Package Manager

Tags: aem

I'm trying to upload a package through the package manager but for some reason the a error is thrown that I couldn't find the reason why.

[image]

The only way that I found in order to solve the problem is to restart the server instance completely, removing the older packages as well.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like multiple bundles providing the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuildFactory interface, I would check which of the currently active bundles export this package to eliminate duplicates.